# Dropdown list and aria live?

Tags: firefox, accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

Is it possible for NVDA to read only the dropdown select value when being loaded with aria live?

```
<div aria-live="polite">
<select>
<option>A</option>
<option selected>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
```

Right now on firefox, it will read A,B,C with no notion of which one is selected. When having plenty of options this becomes an issue since all of the options are being read. Is there a way to mark the select to just read the selected value? "B"

Without aria live the dropdown select is read correctly, just reads "B". Is there a way to achieve this while inside aria live?

Comment: Why do you want this inside an aria-live region? This doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: its an example, the dropdown comes from an ajax request... actually it fetches an entire form the dropdown being inside of it.

Comment: Are you trying to tell the user that the form has arrived? Why not just announce "the example has been updated" and let the user navigate to the example to have it read out?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like the a11yfy live announcer to announce that the example has been updated and then let the user navigate to find the details of the example.

You can download it from Bower. Documentation is here https://github.com/dylanb/a11yfy/blob/master/announce.md#jquerya11yfyassertiveannounce

The code, in case you want to implement yourself is here https://github.com/dylanb/a11yfy/blob/master/a11yfy/jquery.a11yfy.core.js#L29